# Display multiple rickshaw graphs on the same html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, rickshaw

I currently have a couple of dynamically generated JS based Rickshaw graphs similar to http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html

I am kinda new to JS, html etc. How do I go about displaying more than one rickshaw graph on the same html page?

NOTE: I am NOT asking about showing multiple trends on the same graph.

Comment: You should probably consult the documentation.

Comment: I did already, doesnt have any information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have the following graph:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    series: [ { data: [ { x: 0, y: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 4 } ...
    renderer: 'area',
    element: document.querySelector('#graph')
});

graph.render();
```

what you've just done is create a global variable called `graph` that is an instance of the Rickshaw class*, which renders content to the HTML element whose `id` is graph (ie: <div id="graph"></div>).

To render another graph, create a new instance:

```
var graph2 = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    series: [ { data: [ { x: 0, y: 5 }, { x: 1, y: 9 } ...
    renderer: 'area',
    element: document.querySelector('#graph2')
});

graph2.render();
```

... and bind it to a new element:

```
<div id="graph2">
```

*Although Javascript has prototypes rather than classes, it is helpful to think of functions in classical terms sometimes when you are invoking them with the `new` keyword.